# Oracle Apex 22.21 - Popup LOV to Chart - include 'Select All' option as default

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table ORDERS which contains a column STATE which has states based in USA. I have a chart that filters a range of dates with two datepicker items. I want to include another filter where the user clicks a LOV of all the states.

LOV

```
select distinct state
from ORDERS
order by state asc
```

[image]

Is there any way to include an 'ALL' option at the top of the LOV? In which all the states are selected. It would be even better if 'ALL' is selected by default. Without the user having to click it. Currently, the user has to click on at least one state for a report to generate.

Source SQL Query for one of the reports

```
select
        COUNT(ORDER_NUMBER) AS ORDER_COUNT,
       TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE,'YY-MM-DD') AS ORDER_DATE,
       TRUNC(ORDER_DATE)
from ORDER_TOTAL_VIEW
where ORDER_DATE between TO_DATE(:P8_DATE_FROM,'YY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE(:P8_DATE_TO,'YY-MM-DD')
and STATE IN 
  (select regexp_substr(:P8_STATE, '[^:]+', 1, level)
   from dual
   connect by level <= regexp_count(:P8_STATE, ':') + 1
  )
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE,'YY-MM-DD'), TRUNC(ORDER_DATE)
ORDER BY ORDER_DATE ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mind letter case! If you choose to use "All", then it has to be "All", always (not "all", "ALL" or whatever else).

---

Modify List of Values query so that it includes "All" at start of the list:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select 1 rn, 'All' state from dual
  3     union all
  4     select 2 rn, state from orders
  5    )
  6  select state as display_value,
  7         state as return_value
  8  from temp
  9  order by rn, state;

DISPLAY_ RETURN_V
-------- --------
All      All
Alabama  Alabama
Colorado Colorado
Texas    Texas

SQL>
```

Modify query so that it takes into account what's being selected in the LoV:

```
select ...
from order_total_view
where (state = state and :P8_STATE = 'All')
   or (state in (select regexp_substr(:P8_STATE, '[^:]+', 1, level)
                 from dual
                 connect by level <= regexp_count(:P8_STATE, ':') + 1
                )
         and :P8_STATE <> 'All'
      )
```

Set `P8_STATE`s **default value** to `All`. If it doesn't work, include `NVL` function into query (for all references to `P8_STATE`):

```
where (state = state and nvl(:P8_STATE, 'All' = 'All')
                         --------------------
                         this
```

Comment: Thank you for your help on this. This works as expected but I'm trying to figure out why it works.. I have this on another post. Please advise. Thank you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75542642/modify-list-of-values-query-so-that-it-includes-all-at-start-of-the-list-ora