# Modify List of Values query so that it includes "All" at start of the list - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

This is a follow up to a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75459909/oracle-apex-22-21-popup-lov-to-chart-include-select-all-option-as-default/75460097#75460097)

All the details can be found on the previous question to avoid repeating my question. Link above.

Per Littlefoot's answer, I followed his code and steps. His instructions worked and performs as I expected. However, I'm trying to figure out how it works.. (so that next time, I can replicate this myself) If someone could guide and explain to me, it would be much appreciated.

So first, the LOV is as below: (see my comments and questions marked as '--')

```
with temp as                              -- is 'temp' referring to a temporary table? 
(select 1 rn, 'All' state from dual       -- is '1 rn' referring to the first row number?
union all                                 -- not sure how 'All' state from dual works
select 2 rn, state from orders              
)
select state as display_value,
state as return_value
from temp
order by rn, state;
```

My assumptions...

- `with temp as` is creating a temporary table.
- `select 1 rn, 'All' state from dual` is returning 'All' as the first row number. Not sure what `state from dual` does.

Secondly, the query for the LOV:

```
select ...
from order_total_view
where (state = state and :P8_STATE = 'All')
   or (state in (select regexp_substr(:P8_STATE, '[^:]+', 1, level)
                 from dual
                 connect by level <= regexp_count(:P8_STATE, ':') + 1
                )
         and :P8_STATE <> 'All'
      )
```

- I'm not sure how this works `where (state = state and :P8_STATE = 'All')`
- wouldn't it be `where (:P8_STATE = state and :P8_STATE = 'All')`
- Not sure where `and :P8_STATE <> 'All'` comes to play.. is this checking the second `or` statement `and` if `:P8_STATE <> 'All'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is actually being created. `WITH temp` represents a CTE ("common table expression"), also known as the "with factoring clause". It is just a nice/simple way of writing a subquery which can be re-used in the same query several times (if necessary), without repeating the same code all over again.

---

As of `select 1 rn, 'All' state from dual`:

- `1 rn` returns value `1` whose alias is `rn`; you can't have *just* value, it requires an alias (i.e. a *column name*) so that you could reference it later.
- similarly `'All' state means that this is a *column* whose name is` state`and its value is`'All'`.

  - `from dual` - `dual` is an one-row table in Oracle; it is frequently used when you have to select something that doesn't belong to any particular table. For example, if you wanted to know which day is today, you'd `select sysdate from dual`

---

`WHERE` clause should be read as a *whole*. `or` is *crucial* here because it says that

- if you selected `'All'` into `:P8_STATE` item, then you'd select *all rows* from `order_total_view`, hence `state = state`. Could be `1 = 1` or `'ckp' = 'ckp'` or anything else that is *true*.
- if `:P8_STATE <> 'All'`, then it means that you selected one or more states in that item. If there are more states, Apex "stores" them as colon-separated list of values (e.g. `'NY:CA:TX'`) so you used hiererchical subsquery with regular expression which splits that colon-separated string into rows so that they could be used in an `IN` clause. Finally, that piece of code would act as if it were e.g.

  ```
  state in (select 'NY' from dual union all
            select 'CA' from dual union all
            select 'TX' from dual)
  ```

Comment: is that ```state = state``` needed ? The ```:P8_STATE = 'All'``` already yields true so why the ```true and true``` ?

Comment: It is not, @Koen. But helps (me) after a while because it kind of *self-documents* what I wanted to do. "OK, if :P8_STATE = 'All', then state = state. If not, state = (what subquery returns)". Must be something about switches in my brain.

Comment: makes sense - I also like things always the same